# ¿Por qué se usa '%' en este condicional?

Tags: python, condiciones

```
num = 2
var = 'par' if (num% 2 == 0) else 'impar'
```

¿Por qué se pone %?

Comment: % es lo mismo que Mod, devuelve el resultado final de una division. Es decir devuelve el resto de la division entera. si el numero es par siempre sera 0 el mod.

Comment: num % 2 residuo de dividir el valor en num entre 2; si es cero se trata de un par. Los residuos al dividr por 2 son 0 (pares) 1 impares. La línea con que presentas la pregunta no está bien escrita.

Comment: -1 `¿ Por qué se usa ... ?` Está claramente basado en opiniones. Se usa porque el que escribió el código decidió hacerlo así. Un título mas adecuado sería `¿ Que significa ... ?`, en cuyo caso demuestra un inexistente trabajo de investigación: cualquier guía (de las millones que hay) sobre los *operadores en python* explica que es ese operador.

Comment: @Trauma yo edité el titulo así consideré que era más apropiado que el que estaba antes, fue un error mió poner el titulo así.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El símbolo `%` es el operador **módulo**.

La operación módulo es el residuo de una división entera (también llamada [división euclídea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_eucl%C3%ADdea)). Si volvemos a los conceptos básicos de matemática de segundo primaria recordarás que, en la división de un número dentro de otro, al calcular el resultado, que se llama cociente, también se calcula el *residuo* o *resto*, que es *lo que sobra*, o *lo que no se pudo dividir*.

La [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_m%C3%B3dulo), dice al respecto (el énfasis es mio):

> En informática, la operación módulo obtiene el **resto de la división** de un número entre otro (a veces llamado residuo).
>
> Dados dos números positivos, a (el dividendo) y n (el divisor), a módulo n (abreviado como a mod n)​ es el resto de la división euclídea de a entre n. Por ejemplo, la expresión "5 mod 2" se evaluaría a 1 porque 5 dividido entre 2 da un cociente de 2 y un resto de 1, mientras que "9 mod 3" se evaluaría a 0 porque la división de 9 entre 3 tiene un cociente de 3 y da un resto de 0.

### Sobre el código de ejemplo de tu pregunta

En la forma en que se utiliza en el código de tu pregunta, la expresión:

```
(num % 2 == 0)
```

Evaluará a `true` para cualquier número par y a `false` para cualquier número impar.

En otras palabras, se está evaluando si un número es par o no mediante la operación módulo, ya que, para cualquier número par `num`, `num % 2` va a ser cero. Es decir, el residuo de la división de cualquier número par entre dos, es cero.

En cambio, el residuo de cualquier número impar dividido dos, siempre es uno. (tu programa asume correctamente que cualquier valor distinto de cero en la operación módulo es debido a que el operando `num` es impar).

Siendo un poco más exactos, `num % 2` siempre va a devolver `0` o `1`, ya que no puede haber un residuo diferente.

### Generalizando

El operador módulo es utilizado con frecuencia en la escritura de programas, debido a las propiedades o características de la operación:

- Como ya has visto, puedes utilizar la operación módulo para verificar si un número `A` es múltiplo de otro `B`, evaluando si el residuo de la división `A / B` es cero.
- Por lo dicho arriba, con frecuencia se utiliza la operación módulo también para determinar si un número es primo o no, pues generalmente se va evaluando dentro de un ciclo si es múltiplo de otros números pares inferiores.
- Dado que el residuo de una división entre un número `X` siempre te va a devolver un número entre `0` y `X - 1`, es decir, en el intervalo `[0..X)`, la operación también es popular su uso cuando se necesita obtener resultados en cierto rango de números, por ejemplo números aleatorios.

Answer (score 0):

% es la operacion de modulo en resumen si cambias la variable num por cualquier numero impar el resultado te dará un numero distinto de 0 , y en tu codigo quieres el resultado sea 0 para declararlo como un numero par

Answer (score 0):

El operador % o modulo calcula la divisibilidad del numero restándole el segundo valor n veces hasta que este sea cero o el valor positivo mas cercano a 0. En caso el valor sea 0, esto se expresa como que el numero es divisible entre el valor siguiente al operador %.

Por ejemplo: 12%5 arrojara como resultado 2, esto es porque internamente se resto 12-5=7 y luego 7-5=2. Por lo tanto 12 no es divisible entre 5.

En el caso que tu expones, si al usar el *numero*%2 este te arroja cero, esto quiere decir que el numero es divisible entre 2, por ende es par.

Comment: El  hecho de que el módulo se pueda calcular mediante restas (y de hecho se haga en algunos casos) es un mero detalle de implementación. Nada garantiza que un lenguaje (si no lo traduce directamente a una sola instrucción del procesador), procesador o co-procesador matemático particular utilicen ese método/algoritmo para calcular el valor del módulo.

Comment: Me picó la curiosidad, y me parece que, del lado de Intel, no se utiliza lo que explicas para calcular cocientes o residuos, asumiendo que el compilador/interprete ejecute la instrucción [`DIV`](http://jsimlo.sk/docs/cpu/index.php/div.html) para resolver el operador `%`, que creo que es lo que debiera hacer, pero nunca se sabe. Me parece que Intel implementa el operador `div` utilizando el algoritmo [SRT division](http://pages.hmc.edu/harris/research/srtlong.pdf), de hecho, el documento referenciado lo menciona en la sección 2.3.1

Comment: Hay más información sobre el [algoritmo SRT](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://en.wikipedia.org/&httpsredir=1&article=1094&context=hmc_fac_pub), si te interesa el tema.

Comment: Ya para finalizar, Intel, de hecho, en 1996 [patentó su algoritmo](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5784307) para realizar divisiones (enteras y de coma flotante). Por lo que pude ver, la aplicación misma de la patente menciona que la línea **Pentium** implementaba SRT, pero el algoritmo inventado es más eficiente. Es de suponer que los procesadores modernos implementan este algoritmo o alguno más avanzado todavía (ya satisfice mi curiosidad y no voy a seguir buscando). Es de esperar que otros procesadores utilicen algoritmos que son mucho más eficientes que una serie de restas también.

Comment: La patente está expirada, así que otros fabricantes de chips podrían utilizar libremente el mismo algoritmo ahora, aunque pudieron licenciarlo antes. Al menos del lado de RISC. Suena interesante investigar un poco por el lado de ARM.